# How to get values from last month excluding weekends in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

The DAX expression below gives the value by scanning all the dates from the table (VW_RisOrderTable).

```
MAXX(
    VALUES(VW_RisOrderTable[OrderDate].[Date]),
    CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(VW_RisOrderTable[AccessionNo]))
    )
```

I want the value from the last month only and weekends (Saturday & Sunday) should be excluded.
I have tried using `Parellelperiod` but couldn't get the result.

Comment: Dear Peter I have always appreciated volunteer help. I know this formula is not complete or standard that's why I am seeking help. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete but.... If I understood your idea.... you can try creating a new column in your date table.

```
Laboral Day = 
   VAR IsWeekend = Dates[Number Day] IN {6,7}
   

RETURN

   IF (IsWeekend,0,1)
```

This allow you to create a measure filtering days
For example:

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(VW_RisOrderTable[AccessionNo]), Dates[Laboral Day]<>0)
```

I haven't put all your formula but you can realize the rest...
If you want another point of view please improve your question.